# How to add unique suffix for wordwrap() in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to wrap a long text into 140 characters. This doesn't mean i don't need the text after 140 characters. I just need the text to be in chunks of 140 characters each. I first tried chunk_split but that was not up my expectations. Then i tried wordwrap() and that works. But my question though is i figured out how to add a custom "..." at the end of every wrapped string of 137 characters that counts up to 140 chars with "...". But how can i add custom suffix to every wrapped string? like "this is a string (1)", "this is a second string (2)" and so on instead of "..."? Basically i want numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. at the end of every wrapped string instead of the current "..." (dots). Here's my code:

```
<html>
   <form name="longstring" action="longstring.php" method="POST">
      <textarea rows="5" cols="100" name="typehere"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value ="submit">
   </from>

   <br/>

   <?php
      $longstring = $_POST["typehere"];
      echo wordwrap($longstring,137,"...<br>") ;
    ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea:

```
<?php
      $longstring = $_POST["typehere"];
      $wrapped = wordwrap($longstring,137,"<br>");
      $exploded = explode("<br>",$wrapped);
      $i=1;
      foreach($exploded as $x)
      {
        echo $x." (".$i++.") <br>";
      }
?>
```

Output generated by wrapping **13** characters:

```
Lorem Ipsum (1)
is simply (2)
dummy text of (3)
the printing (4)
and (5)
typesetting (6)
industry. (7)
Lorem Ipsum (8)
has been the (9) 

...
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution i found. Thanks a lot RazvanZ.

Answer (score 0):

```
function lines($str, $len, $index = 0) {
    $end = " ($index)\n";
    return (mb_strlen($str) < $len) ? ($str . $end) : mb_substr($str, 0, $len) . $end . lines(mb_substr($str, $len), $len, ++$index);
}


echo lines('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv', 4);
```

the code above will output

```
abcd (0)
efgh (1)
ijkl (2)
mnop (3)
qrst (4)
uv (5)
```

Comment: this one is working to but it gets too complicated for the scope of my script. Thanks anyways got a little idea from this that helped me in my other project i was stuck at!

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "1234567890123456789";
function stspl($str,$len,$index)
{
    $htl="";
    foreach(str_split($str,$len) as $splt)
    {
        $htl.=$splt."($index)\n";
        $index++;
    }
    return $htl;
}
echo  stspl($text,5,1); //here second parameter 5 is the length of chunk that you want... and third parameter is the index from where you want to start means(1) ,(2)
```

Ouput-

```
12345(1)
67890(2)
12345(3)
6789(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many chuncks then you cannot use 137 anymore, after 9 chuncks you would result in a new chunk of 141 chars because of this:

```
137 + strlen("(") + strlen(")") + strlen("10") has a length of 141 chars.
```

This could help:

```
$longstring = "some long string";
$strlen = strlen($longstring);
$a=0;
$b=0;
$c=0;
while($c<$strlen){
  $a++;
  $b=138-strlen($a);
  echo substr($longstring, $c, $b)."(".($a).")<br>";
  $c+=$b;
}
```